# How to find this turning point

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Please help with this algorithm.
I have an array of values 1,2,4,5,4,3,7,8,10,4,5,3,-2,-3
If look at them like chart so we have such chart [image: https://prnt.sc/11z46yo]
(original link: https://prnt.sc/11z46yo)
How to find this turning point? So last max positive value before it becomes 0 or lower. Sorry don't know how describe better.

Comment: With a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that may do what you want.

1. Starting from the end, iterate though the points until you find a negative value or reach the beginning. If you reach the beginning, then there is no turning point. Otherwise continue to step 2.
2. Continue iterating while the values are negative. If you reach the beginning, then there is no turning point. Otherwise record the positive value you found as `candidate` and the index of it as `candidate_index` and continue to step 3.
3. Continue iterating while the values are larger than `candidate`, updating `candidate` and the index of it as `candidate_index`. If the value is not larger, or if you reach the beginning, you are done. The turning point is `candidate` and the index of it is `candidate_index`.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this will find the last turning point in a series

Answer (score 0):

Try test this code. Let's guess your arr list is [1,2,4,5,4,3,7,8,10,4,5,3,-2,-3]

```
def lastTurningPointIndex(arr)
  arr = [1,2,4,5,4,3,7,8,10,4,5,3,-2,-3]
  
  for i in range(len(arr)-1, -1, -1):
    if arr[i] > 0:
      if (arr[i-1] < arr[i]):
        return i
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for a situation when the crossing of the zero line is rotated several times? Like `[1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, -7, -8, 10, 4, 5, 3, -2, -3]`.

I did for your example, assuming one zero crossing.

```
    def find_point(sequence: list) -> tuple:
        """Find the point of maximum value before crossing the zero line."""
        max_value = 0  # init max_value
        for i, value in enumerate(sequence):
            # iterate though the points until you find a negative value
            if value < 0:  # <-- negative value
                for y, rvalue in enumerate(reversed(sequence[:i])):
                    # slice the sequence from start to negative value --> [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10, 4, 5, 3]
                    # reversed --> [3, 5, 4, 10, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1]
                    # iterate though the points while the next value are larger than max_value
                    if rvalue >= max_value:
                        # updating max_value
                        max_value = rvalue
                    else:
                        # when next value are less then max_value, got it
                        # return max_value and point [count to point starts from zero!]
                        return max_value, i - y
```

```
    sequence = [1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10, 4, 5, 3, -2, -3]
    value, point = find_point(sequence=sequence)
    print(value, point, value == sequence[point])  # 5 10 True
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.